# Do Handlebars work with Microsoft Conditional comments?

Tags: html, email, outlook, handlebars.js, conditional-comments

We use conditional comments for our html email templates, as well as handlebars. I'm just wondering if handlebars can be used inside conditional comments like so:

```
                        <div>
                            <!--[if mso]>
                              <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="{{candy.website}}" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:104px;" arcsize="5%" strokecolor="#3ab4e2" fillcolor="#3ab4e2">
                                <w:anchorlock/>
                                <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:'Open Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif;font-size:14px;">View brand</center>
                              </v:roundrect>
                            <![endif]--><a href="www.candies.com"
                        style="background-color: #3ab4e2; border: 1px solid #3ab4e2; border-radius: 2px; color: #ffffff; display: inline-block; font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 40px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; width: 104px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; mso-hide: all;">View brand</a>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out they work just fine!